# How can I solve the normal vertex problem in the Android Build Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, android-build, normals

In my Unity 2022.3.2f1 project, I'm experiencing an issue with normals on a 3D object. The problem is that the normals appear to be incorrect, causing the material to render strangely in the current scene. However, when I move the same object to a different scene, the normals behave correctly, and the material looks fine. Notably, in the Unity Game Preview within the Editor, the object appears as expected, with no issues. However, when I build the project for an Android device, the problem arises. This suggests that the issue may be related to the specific configuration or settings in the Android build, rather than the object or material itself.

[Game preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSTH3.png)
[Android build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGF8w.jpg)

I've already attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

- Checked various aspects of the scene, including camera settings, lighting, and post-processing effects.
- Adjusted normals in Blender.
- Tried adjusting normals within Unity.
- Utilized a script to potentially correct the normals.
  Despite these efforts, the issue with normals persists in the Android build of the game. I'm seeking guidance on how to identify and resolve this problem.

Comment: This could be an animation issue, you can check the quality settings, and check if the issue will be gone without animation.

Comment: Nothing, the issue hasn't changed even after removing the animations and the Animator.
I even have a basic GameObject sphere in the scene, and it's experiencing the same problem.